# excel exclude a certain value from mode average

Tags: excel

I'm looking for a formula that can find the Mode Average from a range of cells but exclude the value 14 from the range

example

```
A1 =26
A2 =14 
A3 =14
A4 =14
A5 =26
A6 =3
A7 =16
A8 =16
A9 =26

Result would be:26 and not 14
```

Comment: I guess `A6` was supposed to be `26`, yes?

Comment: no just put that there for extra numbers in the range I will modify my example with more numbers

Answer (score 4):

Array formulas to the rescue:

```
=MODE(IF(A1:A6 <> 14,A1:A6))
```

Enter it via Ctrl + Shft + Enter

Comment: Always amazing what you can do with Array functions in Excel! This one was a new one for me - thanks!

Comment: You need to enter it using the keyboard combination Ctrl+SHift+Enter

Comment: lol sorry i was been stupid and you did tell me, that awesome very clever, why do you need to use Ctrl+SHift+Enter?

Comment: The ctrl+shift+enter keystroke is required for array formulas. Microsoft must have hired this programmer at one time: http://dilbert.com/strip/1994-02-01

Answer (score 1):

Not very elegant, but it works:

```
=(SUM(C3:C11)-COUNTIF(C3:C11,14)*14)/(COUNT(C3:C11)-COUNTIF(C3:C11,14))
```

`c3:c11` is the range I am looking at on my test sheet.

I am basically looking for the sum of all values in the considered range, subtract 14 times the occurence of the number 14 from this sum and then divide the result by the total number of cells minus the occurences of 14 again. The whole thing will look much nicer, if you have the luxury of another cell that could serve as the "14-counter".

**Edit:** I overlooked the word "mode" in the question. This answer will only compute the average ...

Comment: Hi not sure if the formula is formatted correctly because it doesnt work the countif function I think need "," not an ";" I've tried it both ways I get #DIV/0! result. Can you confirm for us?

Comment: yep, I have to deal with a German Excel variant. It expects a semicolon as a separator between arguments. Just corrected the post for the international audience ...